# Why is this code not in a singleton pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, singleton

According to the design rules, a singleton pattern must exist in an instance. If I remove the line of code and return an object, will the function be a single pattern?

```js
const singleton = (function(){
    
    let instance, 
         counter = 0;
    
    const createInstance = () => ({
        getCounter: () => counter,
        addCounter: (num) => counter += num,
    })
    
    
    return {                                    
        getInsctance: () => createInstance()  //  insctance || (insctance = createInsctance())  ????
    } 
    
})()


const r = singleton.getInsctance()
const r2 = singleton.getInsctance()

r.addCounter(12) 
r2.addCounter(32) 

singleton.counter = 100 

console.log(r2.getCounter()) // 44
console.log(r.getCounter())  // 44
```

Why is this feature not singleton pattern?

Comment: The code you've written doesn't ensure that only one instance of the createInstance object is returned. Every time you call getInsctance, it creates a new object and returns it.

Comment: Depending on what value you want your singleton to point to you can have two answers. Definitely the object that has methods `getCounter`,`addCounter ` is different everytime. But your `counter` is the same everytime. You are thinking you have achieved singleton pattern because the counter is same every time, which is true. But you cannot say the same for the object createInstance creates

Comment: Design patterns are not "rules".  You're welcome to call this a singleton if you want.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, because singleton is a well-defined pattern and it can be factually known whether something is a singleton or not.

Comment: Yes! r2 == r gives false. But why is it bad? The value of the counter inside is private, you can't change it. You can't add "new" here. I do not understand in what situation this code can be bad.

Comment: What do you mean by "*a singleton pattern must exist in an instance*"?

Comment: @СебастианСбербанко An example usage where your code fails to behave as a singleton is `r.test = 1; console.log(r2.test);` (or if you don't like adding new properties, `r.getCounter = () => 1; console.log(r2.getCounter());`. Or when you edit the code and add new things to the objects returned by `getInstance` - after all, "patterns" exist to describe how we develop software, not what the code currently does. The singleton pattern is defined to return the *same* instance every time, so unless you use a weird definition of sameness/object equality, this is not the singleton pattern.

Comment: Imagine you are calling `getInstance` in a tight loop that needs to run as quickly as possible. You're allocating and throwing away objects needlessly.

Comment: @user229044 If everyone calls things however they want, terms loose their meaning. Calling this a singleton pattern is not ok.

Comment: @Bergi I would argue that it is undesirable for one consumer of your Singleton to be able to replace the `getCounter` property, and that you cannot prevent this in JavaScript except by returning a new wrapper around your actual singleton on each call to `getInstance`. Singleton, as described by GoF, depends on a language preventing one consumer from *completely altering the entire singleton instance*. Otherwise it might as well truly be a global variable that anybody is free to overwrite from any place in the code.

Comment: @user229044 yes, of course it's undesirable to do that, still it does demonstrate that it's not a singleton because it behaves in an unexpected way. Sure you can do `createInstance = () => Object.freeze({ getCounter: Object.freeze(() => counter), addCounter: Object.freeze((num) => counter += num) })` to make that example void, but that's not the point. When someone says "singleton", then everyone expects `r === r2`. Breaking that assumption does no good.

Comment: Bergi, thank you. I understood why the code is bad. In a large application, this will cause a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton is a pattern that means that the class/function cannot be a singleton unless there cannot be two instances of it at the same time.

A nice implementation of the singleton pattern can be seen here https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/design-patterns/singleton

```js
var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

function run() {

    var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

    console.log("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2));
}

run();
```

From the outside you cannot call `createInstance`, that is, to protect the pattern and you can call `getInstance`.

Since the requirement of the singleton pattern is to not have more than one instance, you can have 0 instance and you can destroy an object and create another. But you will need to make sure that at all times there will be no more than one instance of that class/function.

Your code is not following the singleton pattern, because, from the outside it can be instantiated even when it's already instantiated:

```js
const singleton = (function(){
    
    let instance, 
         counter = 0;
    
    const createInstance = () => ({
        getCounter: () => counter,
        addCounter: (num) => counter += num,
    })
    
    
    return {                                    
        getInsctance: () => createInstance()  //  insctance || (insctance = createInsctance())  ????
    } 
    
})()


const r = singleton.getInsctance()
const r2 = singleton.getInsctance()

alert((r === r2) ? "it is singleton" : "it is not a singleton")
```

Let's make it a singleton:

```js
const singleton = (function(){
    
    let instance, 
         counter = 0;
    
    const createInstance = () => ({
        getCounter: () => counter,
        addCounter: (num) => counter += num,
    })
    
    
    return {                                    
        getInsctance: () => instance ? instance : (instance = createInstance())  //  insctance || (insctance = createInsctance())  ????
    } 
    
})()


const r = singleton.getInsctance()
const r2 = singleton.getInsctance()

alert((r === r2) ? "it is singleton" : "it is not a singleton")
```

Here I'm reusing the instance instead of creating it if it was already existent.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the Singleton design pattern is that there will only be one instance of the class. Whenever you call the constructor, it should return the same instance. This is typically implemented by creating a new instance the first time the constructor is called, and saving that instance in a variable so that future calls can return it.

In your code this is what the `instance` variable is for. The first time you call `singleton.getInstance()`, the variable is undefined, so the `||` logical operator returns the value of the second expression. This calls `createInstance()`, which creates a new object. It saves this in `instance` and returns it.

Your code acts *like* a singleton because you're not actually storing any data in the instances. You're keeping the counter value in a closure variable that's shared by all instances.

To make a true singleton, you should move `counter` into a property of the object that's returned by `createInstance()`, and use `this.counter` in the other methods. Note that for this to work the methods must be traditional functions rather than arrow functions, because arrow functions don't receive `this` from the method call.

The next time you call `singleton.getInstance()`, the variable `instance` contains that object. So the logical `||` operator returns that value.

Assigning to `singleton.counter` has no effect in either version of the code. In your version, `counter` is a local variable; this is not the same as a property of the object that the IIFE returns. In my version, `counter` is a property of the instance returned by `createInstance()`, which is not the same as `singleton` itself.

```js
const singleton = (function() {

  let instance;

  const createInstance = () => ({
    counter: 0,
    getCounter () {
      return this.counter;
    },
    addCounter (num) {
      this.counter += num;
    },
  })

  return {
    getInstance: () => instance || (instance = createInstance())
  }
})()

const r = singleton.getInstance()
const r2 = singleton.getInstance()

r.addCounter(12)
r2.addCounter(32)

singleton.counter = 100

console.log(r2.getCounter()) // 44
console.log(r.getCounter()) // 44
```

Note that counters are not a good use of the Singleton pattern. Usually you need to create multiple counters, each keeping track of their own sequence of values.